# nested or normal routing in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I am writing blog in rails and I am in half way. I got stuck somehow with routing while implementing edit and deleting comments for an article. I have 3 specific doubts in my mind.

1). To get this kind of url `(http://localhost:3000/articles/54/comments/56/edit)` for blog, Do I need to follow nested routes. I mean

```
 resources :articles do
    resources :comments
  end
```

2) can I get this kind of url without nested routing? If yes, Please give some explanation.

3) Currently, I am trying to implement nested routes ( may be changed after your response). For this kind of routing, Do I need to create "comments" folder inside "articles" folder of views? or can I create "comments"  folder directly under views folder to get nested routes working.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> To get this kind of url for blog, Do I need to follow nested routes.

No, you can use the method `match` to create any route yourself.

> can I get this kind of url without nested routing? If yes, Please give some explanation.

With method `match`,

```
match 'articles/:article_id/comments/:id/edit' => 'comments#edit'
```

more info in the [rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

> Currently, I am trying to implement nested routes ( may be changed after your response). For this kind of routing, Do I need to create "comments" folder inside "articles" folder of views? or can I create "comments" folder directly under views folder to get nested routes working.

For nested routes you should not change the standard folder structure from Rails - that is, the comments folder should be under views folder, not under comments folder. The only moment I'm aware of when you should nest folders in your views/controllers/models directory is when you use a `namespace`.

Edit:

You should look in the semantic of your application to decide if you need nested resources or not. If the CRUD actions you do in your comments are relative to the posts, then you should keep the nested resources, otherwise not.

In this case, I see clearly a nested resource.

Comment: thanks @fotanus , simple and helpful explanation. but according to you, do I continue with nested routes to get this url? Regarding your response to directories structure, so i can create comments folder under views rather than articles folder.

Comment: @VSiingh Glad to help. I was going to answer in this comment, but decided to edit the answer instead to be more visible to users that google to this page.

Comment: hi @fotanus thanks, yes I need to CRUD actions for comments on an article.My doubt is:- is there no need to crate comments folder under aritcles folder to get functionality. thanks again for kind response.

Comment: Yes, no need to create the comment folders under articles, they should be under views, as if the route was not nested. I'll also edit my answer to make this clear

Comment: hi @fotanus, I need nested routes for this and I want to crate comments folder under views folder. is this right approach?